# Unable to get the property for ShowInNewForm

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

i want to know the value for ShowInNewForm for a site column, i tried this PnP:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> connect-pnponline "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/" -UseWebLogin
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $targetField = Get-PnPField -Identity "ApproverFeedbackandnotesPowerBi"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  Write-Host $targetField.ShowInNewForm
```

but i did not get any results.. any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`ShowInNewForm` is a nullable property and **has no value** by default in SharePoint Online.

You will need to update it first to have it return with value. The property can be found in Schema XML once given a value:

```
Connect-PnPOnline "<SiteURL>" -UseWebLogin
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$targetField = Get-PnPField -Identity "ApproverFeedbackandnotesPowerBi" -List <ListName>

$targetField.SetShowInNewForm($true)
$targetField.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$targetField.SchemaXml
```

[image]

You can also use API to get the field properties:

```
https://<SiteURL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<ListName>')/fields
```

Or

```
https://<SiteURL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<ListName>')/fields/getbytitle('ApproverFeedbackandnotesPowerBi')
```